# How to define deduction guide with templated constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, ctad

In order to simplify my problem, I'll be using `std::unique_lock` as the tool to explain.
std::unique_lock has a template argument, the mutex. However, it's constructor is also a template function `unique_lock(TMutex &, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&)`.

When one uses this, one can write:

```
 auto lock = std::unique_lock(my_mutex, 5s);
```

So, the question: How to write out the deduction guide for this (without changing behavior), how to do so?

My best attempt upto now:

```
template<typename _Mutex>
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
unique_lock(_Mutex &, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&) -> unique_lock<_Mutex>;
```

Unfortunately, clang doesn't accept this:

> error: extraneous template parameter list in template specialization or out-of-line template definition

Comment: Have you tried just a single `template`, with three template parameters?

Comment: Not yet, it that works, I'm gonna be confused on why that would be the right way of writing this

Comment: Well, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Looks like that was the trick. Why did they make that inconsistent with defining a function?

Comment: @JVApen It deduces `_Mutex` from the argument type. For example, what if you had `unique_lock<std::decay_t<_Mutex>>` instead?

Comment: @Artyer I'm pretty convinced that should work and I would write it in a way that it explicitly deduces as you suggest.,However, I didn't design `std::unique_lock` and I expect it might misbehave if you move the mutex. (However, as that's not a good idea, I'm not that worried about it)

Comment: why did you split in 2 template? one by argument?

Comment: As for defining a function outside of the class definition, that's the way you write it

Comment: @JVApen For template member functions of template classes, the first template is deduced from `this`. Since there is no `this`, there would be no way to deduce that separately from the arguments so it doesn't make sense

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but aren't `_Names` beginning with underscore followed by a capital letter reserved?

Comment: @Fureeish: they are, I explicitly used an example from the standard library as example for familiarity. I've copied the Ctor from MSVCs implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC has a better error message for this:

> error: too many template-parameter-lists

You can change it to a single template parameter list, like this:

```
template<typename _Mutex, typename _Rep, typename _Period>
unique_lock(_Mutex &, const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&) -> unique_lock<_Mutex>;
```

And it works.

From the comments in your question, you seem to be mixing CTAD and specializations.

You're not specializing anything in `unique_lock`. Not a member function, not a constructor, you're just defining a deduction guide. 
More specifically, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

> The syntax of a user-defined deduction guide is the syntax of a function declaration with a trailing return type [...]
>   A deduction guide is not a function [...]

Notice that it has a syntax of a declaration, not a specialization. It's just different from what you expected.